# How do I change the path to php in phpDocumentor?

Tags: php, phpdoc

I have at least two (probably three) installations of PHP on my machine. phpDocumentor seems to insist upon using `/usr/local/bin/php`, while I would prefer it to use `/usr/local/php5/bin/php`. I haven't been able to find any reference to specifying the path to the interpreter. Is it possible, or should I just symlink to the proper version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, in my phpdoc (`which phpdoc` == `/usr/bin/phpdoc` here), you can just alter the shebang to `#!/usr/local/php5/bin/php`, but I wouldn't want to speculate what happens if I update phpdocumentor...

If you install it with pear, you can:

```
$ sudo pear config-set php_bin /usr/local/php5/bin/php
# remove to reset the package
$ sudo pear uninstall phpDocumentor
$ sudo pear instal phpDocumentor
....
$ head `which phpdoc`
#!/usr/local/php5/bin/php
<?php
/**
```